# Como usar el .isNumeric con un if en java

Tags: java, condiciones, else

Estoy tratando de hacer un código en java que dado 2 números ingresados por el usuario compruebe si son numéricos y si el primer numero ingresado es mayor o menor que el segundo o si son iguales, estoy aprendiendo y se que el código es un desastre, agradecería su ayuda para poner un poco mis ideas en orden.

El código es el siguiente:

```
package ejercicio2condicionalesats;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ejercicio2CondicionalesAts {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    float numero1, numero2;

    numero1 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el primer numero"));
    numero2 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el segundo numero"));

    if (isNumeric(numero1 > numero2)) {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El primer numero es mas grande");

    }         

     else if(isNumeric(numero1 < numero2)) {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El segundo numero es mas grande");

    }

    else {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los numeros son iguales");        


    }
 }

}
```

Comment: No te preocupes por el código,que cuando empezamos siempre es un desastre.  El metodo isNumeric creo que no forma parte de Java, puedes encontrarlo en otras librerías como apache.commons, pero lo que te recomiendo es que lo implementes tu.

Comment: Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a este hilo - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206768/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric

Comment: Un problema que veo en el código es que estás pasando a isNumeric un valor booleano, el valor de numero1 > numero2 será verdadero o falso. La declaración de isNumeric debe aceptar una cadena de caracteres y devolver un valor booleano, true si es un número o false si no lo es. La signatura de isNumeric debería ser algo así: public static boolean isNumeric(String maybeNumer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al declarar las variables **numero1 = Float.parseFloat()** ya le estas indicando al programa que es un valor numérico con decimales. Si lo que quieres es que al introducir los valores, se introduzcan como **string** y luego evaluar si son números, primero deberías hacer la función **isNumeric()** que te devolverá un booleano:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) { 
    try {  
      Double.parseDouble(str);  
      return true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){  
      return false;  
    }  
  }
```

Una vez que tengas esa funcion, el codigo debería de ser algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
package ejercicio2condicionalesats;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ejercicio2CondicionalesAts {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Declaro las variables
    String numero01, numero02;
    Float numero1,numero2;

    //Las siguientes variables se reciben como Strings
    numero01 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el primer numero");
    numero02 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el segundo numero");

    //Se realizan las condiciones sobre las variables String.
    boolean condicion1 = isNumeric(numero01);
    boolean condicion2 = isNumeric(numero02);

    //Se le asignan valores a las variables tipo Float.
    numero1 = Float.parseFloat(numero01);
    numero2 = Float.parseFloat(numero02);

    if ((numero1 > numero2) && condicion1 == true && condicion2 == true) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El primer numero es mas grande");

    }else if((numero1 < numero2) && condicion1 == true && condicion2 == true) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El segundo numero es mas grande");

    }else{

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los numeros son iguales");        

    }
 }

//Funcion isNumeric() que devuelve True o False.
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) { 
    try {  
      Double.parseDouble(str);  
      return true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){  
      return false;  
    }  
  }

}
```

Aunque deberias tener en cuenta que cuando haces lo ya mencionado (declarar las variables como **float** cuando las introduces) te podrías ahorrar el **isNumeric()** porque no es necesario.
El código funcionaría perfectamente de la siguiente manera:

```
package ejercicio2condicionalesats;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ejercicio2CondicionalesAts {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    float numero1, numero2;

    numero1 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el primer numero"));
    numero2 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el segundo numero"));

    if (numero1 > numero2) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El primer numero es mas grande");
    } else if(numero1 < numero2) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El segundo numero es mas grande");
    } else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los numeros son iguales");        
    }
  }
}
```